# Block countries with geoplugin, but allow bots

Tags: php, googlebot

I just lost my google position because the bots can't get access to my site as I was blocking foreign traffic, which included google bot as well.

The plugin used is GeoPlugin, and on this page http://www.geoplugin.com/faq there is an example code

```
function is_bot($user_agent) {

    $botRegexPattern = "(googlebot\/|Googlebot\-Mobile|Googlebot\-Image|Google favicon|Mediapartners\-Google|bingbot|slurp|java|wget|curl|Commons\-HttpClient|Python\-urllib|libwww|httpunit|nutch|phpcrawl|msnbot|jyxobot|FAST\-WebCrawler|FAST Enterprise Crawler|biglotron|teoma|convera|seekbot|gigablast|exabot|ngbot|ia_archiver|GingerCrawler|webmon |httrack|webcrawler|grub\.org|UsineNouvelleCrawler|antibot|netresearchserver|speedy|fluffy|bibnum\.bnf|findlink|msrbot|panscient|yacybot|AISearchBot|IOI|ips\-agent|tagoobot|MJ12bot|dotbot|woriobot|yanga|buzzbot|mlbot|yandexbot|purebot|Linguee Bot|Voyager|CyberPatrol|voilabot|baiduspider|citeseerxbot|spbot|twengabot|postrank|turnitinbot|scribdbot|page2rss|sitebot|linkdex|Adidxbot|blekkobot|ezooms|dotbot|Mail\.RU_Bot|discobot|heritrix|findthatfile|europarchive\.org|NerdByNature\.Bot|sistrix crawler|ahrefsbot|Aboundex|domaincrawler|wbsearchbot|summify|ccbot|edisterbot|seznambot|ec2linkfinder|gslfbot|aihitbot|intelium_bot|facebookexternalhit|yeti|RetrevoPageAnalyzer|lb\-spider|sogou|lssbot|careerbot|wotbox|wocbot|ichiro|DuckDuckBot|lssrocketcrawler|drupact|webcompanycrawler|acoonbot|openindexspider|gnam gnam spider|web\-archive\-net\.com\.bot|backlinkcrawler|coccoc|integromedb|content crawler spider|toplistbot|seokicks\-robot|it2media\-domain\-crawler|ip\-web\-crawler\.com|siteexplorer\.info|elisabot|proximic|changedetection|blexbot|arabot|WeSEE:Search|niki\-bot|CrystalSemanticsBot|rogerbot|360Spider|psbot|InterfaxScanBot|Lipperhey SEO Service|CC Metadata Scaper|g00g1e\.net|GrapeshotCrawler|urlappendbot|brainobot|fr\-crawler|binlar|SimpleCrawler|Livelapbot|Twitterbot|cXensebot|smtbot|bnf\.fr_bot|A6\-Indexer|ADmantX|Facebot|Twitterbot|OrangeBot|memorybot|AdvBot|MegaIndex|SemanticScholarBot|ltx71|nerdybot|xovibot|BUbiNG|Qwantify|archive\.org_bot|Applebot|TweetmemeBot|crawler4j|findxbot|SemrushBot|yoozBot|lipperhey|y!j\-asr|Domain Re\-Animator Bot|AddThis|YisouSpider|BLEXBot|YandexBot|SurdotlyBot|AwarioRssBot|FeedlyBot|Barkrowler|Gluten Free Crawler|Cliqzbot)";


    return preg_match("/{$botRegexPattern}/", $user_agent);

}

if ( !is_bot($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {

// I check for countries I don't want access, and redirect them here     
}
```

The results:

1. Using Proxy surf, it blocks foreign visitors fine
2. Using google bot simulator (https://www.dnsqueries.com/en/googlebot_simulator.php), response: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

I tried multiple attempts such as:

```
function isBot()
{
    $bot_regex = '/BotLink|bingbot|AhrefsBot|ahoy|AlkalineBOT|anthill|appie|arale|araneo|AraybOt|ariadne|arks|ATN_Worldwide|Atomz|bbot|Bjaaland|Ukonline|borg\-bot\/0\.9|boxseabot|bspider|calif|christcrawler|CMC\/0\.01|combine|confuzzledbot|CoolBot|cosmos|Internet Cruiser Robot|cusco|cyberspyder|cydralspider|desertrealm, desert realm|digger|DIIbot|grabber|downloadexpress|DragonBot|dwcp|ecollector|ebiness|elfinbot|esculapio|esther|fastcrawler|FDSE|FELIX IDE|ESI|fido|H�m�h�kki|KIT\-Fireball|fouineur|Freecrawl|gammaSpider|gazz|gcreep|golem|googlebot|google|bot|griffon|Gromit|gulliver|gulper|hambot|havIndex|hotwired|htdig|iajabot|INGRID\/0\.1|Informant|InfoSpiders|inspectorwww|irobot|Iron33|JBot|jcrawler|Teoma|Jeeves|jobo|image\.kapsi\.net|KDD\-Explorer|ko_yappo_robot|label\-grabber|larbin|legs|Linkidator|linkwalker|Lockon|logo_gif_crawler|marvin|mattie|mediafox|MerzScope|NEC\-MeshExplorer|MindCrawler|udmsearch|moget|Motor|msnbot|muncher|muninn|MuscatFerret|MwdSearch|sharp\-info\-agent|WebMechanic|NetScoop|newscan\-online|ObjectsSearch|Occam|Orbsearch\/1\.0|packrat|pageboy|ParaSite|patric|pegasus|perlcrawler|phpdig|piltdownman|Pimptrain|pjspider|PlumtreeWebAccessor|PortalBSpider|psbot|Getterrobo\-Plus|Raven|RHCS|RixBot|roadrunner|Robbie|robi|RoboCrawl|robofox|Scooter|Search\-AU|searchprocess|Senrigan|Shagseeker|sift|SimBot|Site Valet|skymob|SLCrawler\/2\.0|slurp|ESI|snooper|solbot|speedy|spider_monkey|SpiderBot\/1\.0|spiderline|nil|suke|http:\/\/www\.sygol\.com|tach_bw|TechBOT|templeton|titin|topiclink|UdmSearch|urlck|Valkyrie libwww\-perl|verticrawl|Victoria|void\-bot|Voyager|VWbot_K|crawlpaper|wapspider|WebBandit\/1\.0|webcatcher|T\-H\-U\-N\-D\-E\-R\-S\-T\-O\-N\-E|WebMoose|webquest|webreaper|webs|webspider|WebWalker|wget|winona|whowhere|wlm|WOLP|WWWC|none|XGET|Nederland\.zoek|AISearchBot|woriobot|NetSeer|Nutch|YandexBot|YandexMobileBot|SemrushBot|FatBot|MJ12bot|DotBot|AddThis|baiduspider|SeznamBot|mod_pagespeed|CCBot|openstat.ru\/Bot|m2e/i';
    $userAgent = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? FALSE : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $isBot = !$userAgent || preg_match($bot_regex, $userAgent);

    return $isBot;
}
```

and

```
function is_bot() {

    return (
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
        && preg_match('/bot|google|crawl|slurp|spider|mediapartners/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
      );
}
```

Yet always the same results: Always blocks the bots, no matter what. All I want is to decide which countries I will allow (already achieved) and stop bots from reacting on this.

Has anyone achieved to block/allow certain countries, without affecting google bots?

Comment: You do realize 302 Moved Temporarily isn't an error, right? It's probably your webserver redirecting non-www to www, or non-https to https or something, but the above script should work

Answer (score -1):

You should not block countries. Maybe there will be some other reasons for the ranking drop. 
When you use block countries tag then it will apply on both visitors and Bots too.
So please dont use these tags. Otherwise you will always hurt.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. I respect your opinion, but that doesn't change the fact that I still need to accomplish the requested. Help or code examples to solve the issue would be very much appreciated.